Do I need Abu Dhabi visa?
I am travelling from UK to Islamabad, Pakistan and my overlay is at Abu Dhabi. As it’s a 18 hours I was hoping to roam around and book a hotel to sleep.
My question is do I need a visa? I am flying via etihad airway and I have Pakistani passport but my family has EU passport.

As a Pakistan citizen, you will need a visa if you wish to pass through immigration and enter the country.
However as your transit time is less than 24 hours you do not need a visa if you stay airside.  There is a hotel located airside that can be used whilst in transit, however you can expect prices be higher than you would pay outside of the airport.

Being EU citizens, your family members are most likely eligible for a visa on arrival.
In your own case, you will need a transit visa. Since you fly with Etihad, you can get the visa through them.
Info is available here. You can apply online. There's a 55 AED fee for the visa.
Regarding the hotel, you may be eligible for a free hotel (and a number of other discounts), see here for details.

I checked with Etihad and if you have purchases ticket from 3rd party website you do not get free hotel. just wanted to add to the answer
